# what is the Jquery script to make the FIRST WORD in each sentence bold?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the first word of each sentences bold using jquery. This is for a project that am currently doing. I have left the jquery blank, any help would be much appreciated.

All other i have seen is about making the first letter in a word capital, but i need first word bold in each sentences.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>First Sentence</p>
<p>Second Sentence</p>
<p>Third Sentence</p>
<p>Fourth Sentence</p>
<p>Fivth Sentence</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is what you want same as making first word of every `p` tag bold?

Comment: You should try something yourself before asking here, to show that you have made an attempt. It doesn't have to be the full code, but something like the structure for looping all `<p>` elements would be a start

Comment: Did you try something? Show some effort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('p').each(function(){  
    var pdata = $(this);  
    pdata.html( pdata.text().replace(/(^\w+)/,'<strong>$1</strong>') );  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body> 
<p>First Sentence</p>
<p>Second Sentence</p>
<p>Third Sentence</p>
<p>Fourth Sentence</p>
<p>Fivth Sentence</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Here can I use addClass method to make the first word of each sentence bold?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('p').each(function(){

var me = $(this);

me.html(me.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('p').each(function() {
         var html = $(this).html();
         var word = html.substr(0, html.indexOf(" "));           
         var rest = html.substr(html.indexOf(" "));
         $(this).html(rest).prepend($("<span/>").html("<b>"+word+"</b>") );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>First Sentence</p>
<p>Second Sentence</p>
<p>Third Sentence</p>
<p>Fourth Sentence</p>
<p>Fivth Sentence</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<html>
<body>
 <p>First Sentence</p>
 <p>Second Sentence</p>
 <p>Third Sentence</p>
 <p>Fourth Sentence</p>
 <p>Fivth Sentence</p>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var all = $("p");                          // Select all p tag

    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){            //Iterate over the collection

        var html = $(all[i]).html();          //get html
        var firstWord = html.split(" ")[0];   //get first word

        var boldFirstWord = "<b>"+firstWord+"</b>";   // make first word bold html syntax

        var newhtml = html.replace(firstWord, boldFirstWord);  // replace firstword with upper case word

        $(all[i]).html(newhtml);              // replace the html
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed somehow. Updated the ans. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and `join` will do this. I make it step by step for you to understand.

```
$("p").each(function() { 
  var p = $(this).text();
  var splt = p.split(' ');
  var s = splt[0].split("");
  var x = "<strong>" + s[0] + "</strong>";
  s[0] = x;
  splt[0] = s.join("");

  $(this).html(splt.join(" "));
});
[Fiddle][1]
```

Comment: this gives only the first letter not the first word.

Comment: No it will give you the entire content of `p`

Answer (score 0):

An other way, shorter, 0-jQuery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<p>First Sentence</p>
<p>Second Sentence</p>
<p>Third Sentence</p>
<p>Fourth Sentence</p>
<p>Fivth Sentence</p>

<script>

  for(li of document.querySelectorAll('body > p'))
  {

    let words = li.innerHTML.split(' ');

    li.innerHTML = "<strong>"+words.shift()+"</strong> "+words.join(' ');

  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<strong>'+$(this).text()[0]+'</strong>'+$(this).text().substring(1));
});
```

... or...

```
$('p').each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = '<strong>' + this.textContent[0] + '</strong>' + this.textContent.substring(1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do the trick.....I was looking for a simpler answer as I am still a beginner, I didn't want to simply copy paste.

But thanks to all who responded.

```
 <style>
.first-word{
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<body>

<p>First Sentence</p>
<p>Second Sentence</p>
<p>Third Sentence</p>
<p>Fourth Sentence</p>
<p>Fivth Sentence</p>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('p').each(function() {
            var word = $(this).html();
            var index = word.indexOf(' ');
            if(index == -1) {
                index = word.length;
            }
            $(this).html('<span class="first-word">' + word.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + word.substring(index, word.length));
        });
        $(document).on("contextmenu",function(){
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with some special characters, and only the letters up to that special char will get bold-ed.
Instead, use /S to fix it.

example:
Ståle Solbakken efter stor europæisk nedtur

/w will return **St**åle Solbakken efter stor europæisk nedtur

while

/S will correctly return **Ståle** Solbakken efter stor europæisk nedtur